# SAS changes all numerics to length 8 even when input data sets define numerics otherwise

Tags: sas

I have two input datasets which I need to interweave.  The input files have defined lengths for numeric fields depending on the size of the integer.  When I interweave the datasets -- either a DATA or PROC SQL statement -- the lengths of numeric fields are all reset to the default of 8.  Outside of explicitly defining the length for each field in a LENGTH statement, is there an option for SAS to keep the original attributes of the input columns?

More details ...

data A ;

length numeric_variable 3 ;

{input data}
;

data B ;

length numeric_variable 3 ;

{input data}
;

data AB ;

set A B ;
by some_id_variable ;

{stuff};

;

In the data set AB, the variable NUMERIC_VARIABLE is length 8 instead of 3.  I can explicitly put another length statement in the "data AB" statement, but I have tons of columns.

Comment: Why do you care?

Comment: Length for numeric variables refers to bytes. Honestly, its best to leave it at 8 as default rather than changing it, unless you have a very specific reason. Sometimes it makes sense to make it smaller to save space but you usually need large data sets for that and you can always use the compress option instead.

Comment: Tom is correct below.  I misidentified where the problem occurred and confused myself when I checked both the SQL and DATA statement alternatives.

Comment: ... but to answer the questions, the files are long and wide.  So I wanted to skip writing additional code to keep the storage requirements down.  Anyway, I thought I was being careful before posting and tried to give a super simple example to ensure that my question was clear.  My apologies to everyone ... but thank you for your time since you answered my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is wrong.  A data step will set the length based on how it is first defined.  If you just select the variable in SQL it keeps its length. However in SQL if you are doing something like UNION that combines variables from different sources then the length will be set to 8.

Example:

```
data one; length x 3; x=1; run;
data two; length x 5; x=2; run;
data one_two; set one two; run;
data two_one; set two one; run;
proc sql ;
  create table sql_one as select * from one;
  create table sql_two as select * from two;
  create table sql_one_two as select * from one union select * from two;
  create table sql_two_one as select * from two union select * from one;
quit;

proc sql;
 select memname,name,length 
 from dictionary.columns
 where libname='WORK'
   and memname like '%ONE%'
   or  memname like '%TWO%'
 ;
quit;
```

Results:

```
                                                                      Column
Member Name                       Column Name                         Length
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ONE                               x                                        3
ONE_TWO                           x                                        3
SQL_ONE                           x                                        3
SQL_ONE_TWO                       x                                        8
SQL_TWO                           x                                        5
SQL_TWO_ONE                       x                                        8
TWO                               x                                        5
TWO_ONE                           x                                        5
```

So if you want define your variables then either add the length statement as you mentioned or create a template datasets and reference that in your data steps before referencing the other dataset(s). For complex SQL code you will need to include the LENGTH= option in your SELECT clause to force the lengths for the variables you are creating.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.  This is my problem.  I thought that I tried both -- SQL UNION and DATA statements -- but I misidentified where the problem occurred in a stream of steps.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post code that demonstrates the problem?

This code does NOT exhibit a final data set in which the numeric lengths get changed from 3 to 8.

```
data A;   id = 'A';   length x 3;   x=1;
data B;   id = 'A';   length x 3;   x=2;
data AB;
  set A B;
  by id;
run;
proc contents data=AB; run;
```

Contents

```
#    Variable    Type    Len

1    id          Char      1
2    x           Num       3
```

Comment: Geez ... sorry about this.  I thought that both scenarios were tested in my stream of code but I misidentified where it started.